# Update cart function adds new items instead of updating existing

Tags: php

When a user clicks on 'add to cart', an ajax request is made and the item is added to the cart. The product ID is retrieved, the required details are then extracted from the database and put into a cart session array. This all works fine.

```
public function AddToCart()
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $quantity = 1;
        $prod_id = $_POST['prod_id'];
        $prod_data = $this->ProductFendModel->GetProductByIdCart($prod_id);

        $data = [
            'prod_name' => $prod_data->prod_name,
            'sale_price' => $prod_data->sale_price,
            'sp_name' => $prod_data->sp_name    
        ];

        $response = array();
        $message = '';    
        $key = "{$prod_id}";

        if (empty($_SESSION['cart_array'][$key])) {
            $_SESSION['cart_array'][$key] = array(
                'prod_id' => $prod_id,
                'quantity' => $quantity,
                'prod_name' => $data['prod_name'],
                'sale_price' => $data['sale_price'],
                'sp_name' => $data['sp_name']
            );
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['cart_array'][$key]['quantity'] += $quantity;
        }

        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Product added to cart';

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

But, when I try to update the cart it duplicates the existing items with the correct quantities instead of just updating the quantities of what is already in the cart. For example, if I had 2 items in the cart, I now get 4. The first 2 have the original quantities and the newly added 2 have the correct quantities.

```
public function UpdateCart()
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        foreach($_POST['prod_id'] as $key => $id)
        {
            $qty = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
            $_SESSION['cart_array'][$key]['quantity'] = $qty;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is in UpdateCart you are accessing $_POST['prod_id'] as an associative array, but as an integer in AddToCart.
`foreach($_POST['prod_id'] as $key => $id)`
vs
`$prod_id = $_POST['prod_id'];`.
Also, don't forget to filter your POST variables before you use this in production! It is really good practice, even if you are just writing the data to the session and can even allow you to sanitize by type so that you can be more certain that you have that control during runtime.

If this doesn't point you in the right direction, you might consider posting the $_SESSION and $_POST dumps. Also, if you are not already doing so, use PHPUnit. It is not very complicated to use, even though there are best ways of using it.

As for the request variables, you can pass an array to the function or your class instead of accessing state variables directly from within the function. Doing this keeps you from over-complicating the logic and allows you to keep a larger portion of the application design in your short-term working memory.